# Pass methods with arguments to wrapper component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

is it possible to pass/connect methods to wrapper component with arguments? Let me explain...

In redux app I have two components WrapperComponent and ComposedComponents (eg. ComposedComponent1, ComposedComponent2) which should be wrapped by wrapper component. Previously I had some methods/actions connected to ComposedComponents (some methods connected to ComposedComponent1 and different to ComposedComponent2). These methods need arguments (eg. this.props.user, this.props.params.itemId, etc - depending on method).
Now I would like to wrap each ComposedComponent pass proper methods to WrapperComponent (with proper param/argument) fire passed methods in WrapperComponent, do stg else and render ComposedComponent. I do not really know if it is possible to pass methods with proper argument to WrapperComponent.

Now in one of ComposedComponent I have something like that:

```
import WrapperComponent from './Wrapperomponent'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { getUser, getItem } from '../actions/exampleActions'

class ComposedComponent extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.getUser(this.props.params.userId)
        this.props.getItem(this.props.item)
    }
    render(){
        return (something)
    }
}
```

I modified it to use WrapperComponent (but without passing arguments):

```
class ComposedComponent extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return (something)
    }
}

export default connect(null,{ getUser, getItem })(WrapperComponent(connect(mapStateToProps)(ComposedComponent)))
```

But in general I'm trying to achieve something like:

```
export default connect(null,{ 
    getUser(this.props.params.userId), 
    getItem(this.props.item) 
})(WrapperComponent(connect(mapStateToProps)(ComposedComponent)))
```

Is it achievable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Option 1:

As i understand you are trying to pass into the component a method that has an ID already bound to it. This can be achieved like this:

First, The component could look like this. It can use methods getTheUser() and getTheItem() without providing the ID.

```
/* ComposedComponent.js(x) */
class ComposedComponent extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.getTheUser();
        this.props.getTheItem();
    }
    render(){
        return (something)
    }
}
```

The wrapper/container could bind the ID beforehand like this:

```
// WrapperComponent.js(x)

import ComposedComponent from './ComposedComponent'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { getUser, getItem } from '../actions/exampleActions'

//First, extract the user id from state
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        userId: state.where.you.get.user.id
    };
}
// Then get your action and bind the dispatch to it
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        getUser: (userId) => dispatch(getUser(userId));
    }
}
//Now take the user id and bind it also to the action
function mergeProps(stateProps, dispatchProps) {
    const {userId} = stateProps;
    const {getUser} = dispatchProps;

    return {
        getThisUser: () => getUser(userId)
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, mergeProps)(ComposedComponent);
```

## (Better) Option 2:

Second option is not to bind the id. It is also [reccomended solution by gaearon](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/237#issuecomment-168819375): "This is not as elegant but it's much more performant and also easier to understand than a complex connect() declaration."

So the component receives both the method and id as a prop:

```
/* ComposedComponent.js(x) */
class ComposedComponent extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.getUser(this.props.userId);
        this.props.getItem(this.props.userId);
    }
    render(){
        return (something)
    }
}
```

And the container just provides the container with all the methods and ID's it might need:

```
// WrapperComponent.js(x)

import ComposedComponent from './ComposedComponent'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { getUser, getItem } from '../actions/exampleActions'

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        userId: state.where.you.get.user.id
    };
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        getUser: (userId) => dispatch(getUser(userId));
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ComposedComponent);
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I get it. If I have in my app many ComposedComponents (eg. ComposedComponent1, ComposedComponent2, ..., 20). How can I reuse WrapperComponent in your solution?

Comment: If the components are really similar, then i would join them into one. Then wrapper could give one more property, that tells which variation of ComposedComponent to render.

If you want to switch between the components, then you could have one more pure component between Wrapper and Component, that looks something like this:

render() {

Comment: render(){
        switch(componentType) {
            case 1:
                 return <ComposedComponent1 />
            case 2:
                 return <ComposedComponent2 />
     }